# CodeIgniter Cache - Naming files and turning md5 off

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, md5

I heard that

> they are hash  md5($uri); of your URI. so its similar to
>   controllername+function name but in a hashed format.

Why codeigniter hashes files named `controller_name+function` with md5? Is it necessary? Or security option? Even if, what does it secure and how?

And main question, Can I turn it off, to have files in cache folder named like 'controller+function' ? And how to achieve it?

Comment: No one no idea?

Comment: Any idea? Guys.